# Error during template rendering?

Tags: python, django

I have a blog app, this is the relevant part of views.py, of course belonging to the blog app.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Blog

# Create your views here.
def view_homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

def view_aboutpage(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})

def view_blogpost(request, blog_id):
    article = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'damn.html', {'article':article})
```

this is the urls.py in blog app

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, patterns
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.view_homepage, name=''),
  url(r'about/$', views.view_aboutpage, name='about'),
  url(r'blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$', views.view_blogpost, name='post'),
]
```

This is the regular urls.py in the project.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

This is the error, I am having.

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.              1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<blog_id>\\d+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.     1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<blog_id>\\d+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\filip\Python\ENV\lib\site-    packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
Python Executable:  C:\Users\filip\Python\ENV\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.1
```

This is the html:

```
<li>
    <a href="{% url "" %}">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{% url "about" %}">About</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{% url "post" article.id %}">Sample Post</a>
</li>
```

> Reverse for 'post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P\d+)/$']

Answer (score 4):

Like the error says, you don't have a URL called "post" that takes no arguments; the URL you do have called that is expecting a blog_id argument. So, you should pass that in your tag; since you have a context variable called `article` it would be:

```
<a href="{% url "post" article.id %}">Sample Post</a>
```

Comment: That doesn't work.
I tried with {% url "post" blog_id.id %},
So, should I change the views.py?

Comment: function that call one object is ok, update question with function, who render all blog_posts

Comment: I realise that according to the view you've posted, the context variable is `article`, so you should use `article.id`; I've updated my code.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, that still doesn't work, my exception changed to "with arguments '('',)' " from "with arguments '()'".

Comment: Actually, as Baterson pointed out, the view that you've shown is the one for the individual post. But the one that's rendering the HTML that's causing the problem is view_homepage. Actually, you should simply show more of the template itself, as we need to know how you are iterating through your posts in that template. (Although again, you should really be able to work this out by yourself now given the help you've already received.)

Comment: I'm trying to learn, it's more of a hobbie than anything. Anyway I updated the html part. By the way, if I remove the line that we are tying to fix it works.

Comment: @AquaSolid it is not enough, you just add some links, that cant help solve your problem.

Comment: @Baterson, well, everything else is irrelevant, they have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: The point that you don't seem to be grasping is that if you want to link to a post you need to include the ID of that post; and that ID has to come from somewhere. In that sample HTML you don't have any variable that includes a post ID, so I'm not sure how you're expecting any of it to work.

Comment: @AquaSolid I think you create view, that get `articles = Article.objects.all()` , than render it in template by template tage `{% for article in articles %}` , am I right? So we need to see this code, for help you

Comment: I am expecting it to work, because it worked for this person (https://youtu.be/PHiSlGPxwBk?t=8m26s). I am following his tutorials. And, @Baterson, I already have Blog models with a Blog class which is responsible for making blog.objects.

Comment: @AquaSolid so put code from `view`, when you render this objects on page, I definatly sure problem with this part

Comment: As I said above, *where are you expecting the id to come from*?

Comment: If I just leave it at <a href="/blog">Sample Post</a> everything works even the regex. I am expecting the id to come from the models, as in the scenario where someone clicks a link and gets transferred to a new page, each article should have a unique ID number.

Comment: Aargh. But in order to get the id from the model, you actually have to have an instance of the model whose id you want. How can that not be clear?